# issue about return message on Paypal ExpressCheckout

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I recived ACK message 'Success' but PAYMENTSTATUS message is 'Denied'.
And I can not find transaction history.

This Payment is Failue? Or Is it possible change to 'Completed'?

I don't understand there is message 'Success' with 'Denied'

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this page for payment status definitions](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/helpcenter/article/?articleID=94021&m=SRE).

Do you have fraud filters setup that could be automatically denying payments under certain circumstances?